# How do I solve this error of hadoop in windows 10?

Tags: hadoop, installation, hdfs

When I enter 
`hadoop fs -put Pras.txt`
I face this error

```
put: Call From LAPTOP-EOKJS2KE/192.168.56.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

I edited to this in hdfs-site.xml

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?> 
<configuration>     
    <property> 
        <name>dfs.replication</name>        
        <value>1</value>    
    </property> 
    <property>      
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>       
        <value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value>  
    </property>     
    <property>       
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>       
        <value>C:\hadoop\data\datanode</value>  
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

And edited to this in core-site.xml

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The service that's expected to be running on your laptop seems to be down. It should have been running and listening on port 9000. Check that out.

Comment: I don't understand what should I do exactly.

Comment: Please paste the content of `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml`.

Comment: Please remove the details from the comment section and paste it in your original post by updating it.